# Maclaurin expansion of $\arctan(x)/(1 − x).$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, analysis, taylor-expansion

How was [this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0132296381) Maclaurin expansion derived? For each $|x|<1,$
\begin{align} \left( \frac{\arctan(x)}{1-x} \right)&=\left( \sum^{\infty}_{k=0}x^k\right)\left(\sum^{\infty}_{j=0}\dfrac{(-1)^j x^{2j+1}}{2j+1}\right)\\&= \sum^{\infty}_{k=0}\left(\sum_{j\in D_k} \dfrac{ (-1)^{j} }{2j+1}\right)x^k,\;\text{where}\; D_k=\{j\in \Bbb{N}:0\leq j\leq (k-1)/2\}.\end{align}

**HERE'S MY TRIAL**

\begin{align} \left( \frac{\arctan(x)}{1-x} \right)&=\left( \sum^{\infty}_{k=0}x^k\right)\left(\sum^{\infty}_{j=0}\dfrac{(-1)^j x^{2j+1}}{2j+1}\right)\\&= \sum^{\infty}_{k=0}\left(\sum^{k}_{j=0} x^j\dfrac{ (-1)^{(k-j)} x^{2(k-j)+1}}{2(k-j)+1}\right),\;\text{for}\; k\in \Bbb{N}\\&\stackrel{\text{how?}}{=} \sum^{\infty}_{k=0}\left(\sum_{j\in D_k} \dfrac{ (-1)^{j} }{2j+1}\right)x^k.\end{align}

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking here. Do you want a different expansion? This is a fairly straightforward approach.

Comment: @robjohn: I have edited it. Thanks.

Comment: Look up the [Cauchy product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_product).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The idea here is to use the [Cauchy Product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_product). However, since one series has exponents of $k$ and the other series has exponents of $2j+1$, we need to extract the essence of the product formula: that is, for a given $m$, the products of which terms give $x^m$? That would be when $k+2j+1=m$. Thus, the coefficient of $x^m$ in the final product is
$$
\sum_{j=0}^{\left\lfloor\frac{m-1}2\right\rfloor}\overbrace{\vphantom{b}\ a_{m-2j-1}\ }^{\substack{\text{coefficient}\\\text{of $x^{m-2j-1}$}}}\overbrace{\ \ \ \ \ b_j\ \ \ \ \ }^{\substack{\text{coefficient}\\\text{of $x^{2j+1}$}}}
$$
That is,
$$
\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_kx^k\sum_{j=0}^\infty b_jx^{2j+1}
=\sum_{m=0}^\infty\sum_{j=0}^{\left\lfloor\frac{m-1}2\right\rfloor}a_{m-2j-1}b_jx^m
$$
Since $a_k=1$ for all $k\ge0$, we have
$$
\sum_{m=0}^\infty\sum_{j=0}^{\left\lfloor\frac{m-1}2\right\rfloor}\overbrace{\ \frac{(-1)^j}{2j+1}\ }^{b_j}x^m
$$

Comment: (+1) Thanks for the correction.

Answer (score 1):

**Corrected:** Thanks to robjohn for the mentorship. Since 
\begin{align} \left( \sum^{\infty}_{k=0}a_k x^k\right)\left( \sum^{\infty}_{j=0}b_j x^j\right)&=\sum^{\infty}_{r=0}\left( \sum^{r}_{j=0}b_j  a_{r-j} \right)x^{r},\;\text{where}\; r=k+j\;\text{and}\;r\in\Bbb{N},.\end{align}
we have that,

\begin{align} \left( \frac{\arctan x }{1-x} \right)&=\left( \sum^{\infty}_{k=0}a_k x^k\right)\left( \sum^{\infty}_{j=0}b_j x^{2j+1}\right)\\&=\sum^{\infty}_{\gamma=0}\left( \sum^{\frac{\gamma-1}{2}}_{j=0}b_j  a_{\gamma-2j-1} \right)x^{\gamma},\;\text{where}\; \gamma=k+2j+1\;\text{and}\;\gamma\in\Bbb{N},\\&=\sum^{\infty}_{\gamma=0}\left( \sum^{\frac{\gamma-1}{2}}_{j=0}\dfrac{  (-1)^{j} }{2j+1}  \right)x^{\gamma},\\&= \sum^{\infty}_{\gamma=0}\left(\sum_{j\in D_\gamma} \dfrac{ (-1)^{j} }{2j+1}\right)x^\gamma.\end{align}
where $D_\gamma=\{j\in \Bbb{N}:0\leq j\leq (\gamma-1)/2\},\;a_{\gamma-2j-1} =1,\,j\in D_\gamma ,\;b_j= (-1)^{j} /(2j+1).$

Comment: In the last set of equations, the second line is wrong for exponents $k$ and $2j+1$, and the upper limit in the inner sum on the third line does not make sense because $j$ is the variable of iteration. It is not obvious how $\frac{\gamma-1}2$ appears in the fourth line (especially since that line says $\gamma=k+2j+1$ which is the upper limit in the prevous line).

Comment: @robjohn: Will fix it.

Comment: @robjohn: I have fixed it. Thank you!